# Laravel Deployment Failed using Vapor

Tags: laravel, deployment, devops

what can I do if I have failed in laravel deployment as the following:

Deployment hook failed.
Hook: migrate --force
Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'bio'
Logs: You may review its logs using the `hook:log 1178007` command.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMYFU.png)
I don't have access to vapor, can I do something about this error??

Comment: problem is happening as duplicate column is inserting in table. 
please check your migration before add_bio_to_user_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a problem of recreating new column that was already added before.

You can make sure to validate on this column before creating it like the following:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('table-name', function (Blueprint $table) {
      if (! Schema::hasColumn('table-name', 'col-name')) {
         $table->text('col-name')->nullable();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it solves the issue.